Stream a Large file in chunks and process it while its still receiving in MultiPartFile in spring-boot-starter-web
I wanted to read CSV file which might have millions of records, read the file while upload itself, rather than waiting for whole file to be uploaded.
I wanted to process it as its received in chunks. (process the file contents even before the full file uploaded , process in parts)
I was able to analyze how it can be done for the spring-boot-starter-webflux.
but my application is spring-boot-starter-web.
My implementation for the spring-starter-webflux.
@PostMapping("/upload")
public Mono<Void> uploadFile2(@RequestPart("file") FilePart filePart) {
    StringBuilder accumulator = new StringBuilder();

    return filePart.content()
            .doOnNext(dataBuffer -> {
                System.out.println("------------------------ Processing started ----------------------------");
            })
            .map(dataBuffer -> {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[dataBuffer.readableByteCount()];
                dataBuffer.read(bytes);
                return new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            })
            .flatMap(content -> {
                accumulator.append(content);
                String accumulatedContent = accumulator.toString();
                String[] lines = accumulatedContent.split("\n");

                // Process all complete lines
                for (int i = 0; i <= lines.length - 1; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Processing line: " + lines[i]);
                }

                // Check if the last character of the accumulated content is a newline
                if (accumulatedContent.charAt(accumulatedContent.length() - 1) == '\n') {
                    // The last line is complete
                    accumulator.setLength(0); // Clear the accumulator
                } else {
                    // The last line is incomplete, keep it in the accumulator
                    accumulator.setLength(0);
                    accumulator.append(lines[lines.length - 1]);
                    System.out.println("last line incomplete - " + accumulator);
                }

                return Mono.empty();
            })
            .then(Mono.defer(() -> {
                // Process any remaining content in the accumulator
                if (accumulator.length() > 0) {
                    System.out.println("Processing last line: " + accumulator.toString());
                }
                return Mono.empty();
            }));
}

How can i implement this same functionality in spring-boot-starter-web.
I tried using apache-commons-fileupload.
The implementation for the apache commons-fileupload in spring-boot-starter-web:
  @PostMapping("/upload")
public String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request) {

    System.out.println("-------------------------- Start ---------------------");
    if (!JakartaServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
        return "Error: Form must have enctype=multipart/form-data.";
    }

    JakartaServletFileUpload upload = new JakartaServletFileUpload();

    try {
        var iter = upload.getItemIterator(request);
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("--------------------- CHUNK --------------------");
            FileItemInput item = iter.next();
            String name = item.getFieldName();
            InputStream stream = item.getInputStream();
            if (item.isFormField()) {
                System.out.println("Form field " + name + " with value " + Streams.asString(stream) + " detected.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("File field " + name + " with file name " + item.getName() + " detected.");

                // Read InputStream into a byte array
                byte[] fileBytes = stream.readAllBytes();

                // Save the file
                File destinationFile = new File("C:\\Users\\anon\\Desktop\\output\\"
                        + new Random().nextInt(100000) + ".csv");
                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile)) {
                    fos.write(fileBytes);
                }

                // Create a new InputStream from the byte array
                try (InputStream newStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes)) {
                    System.out.println(readFromInputStream(newStream));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
    }

    return "File uploaded successfully.";
}

public static String readFromInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
    System.out.println("--------------- processing chunk -------------");
    StringBuilder resultStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            resultStringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resultStringBuilder.toString();
}

but this is not receiving the file in chunks.
Any help on how to do it in Spring-boot-starter-web would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

To implemen chunked  file processing , you can take a try  with Aynscontext which in servlet 3..0 combinate with  your code snippet ,that's  allow you read file in chunk ,when  file is being uploading , rather than waiting for entire be uploaded.
